# BMW cranking but won't start

Tags: starting, bmw, diesel

My BMW is turning over but won't start, fuel pressure is as it should and the there is no faults showing except for 4 glow plug on, but I'm told this shouldn't stop the car from starting, any ideas what the problem may be?

Comment: More details about the car? Year/model/egine/miles?

Comment: And whay is the ambient air temperature when you are attempting to start?  Glow plugs might be necessary for starting.

Comment: It would also help to know recent work on the car. I assume it is a diesel? How vigorously is it turning over? Some ECUs don't start injecting fuel until a certain speed is reached and a low battery might not be able to make the speed. Would also be worth having someone look at the exhaust. Do you smell fuel? Is there a faint haze/cloud? Did this come on suddenly?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, its a 2005 525d recently has gotten the ecu replaced as the last one had water damage, that's when fuel pressure became normal again. Car is cranking at a good rate, fuel is getting to the injectors, car needs gasket around manifold and thats it

Comment: Car used to be slow to start first thing but once going it was fine this lead to starter burning out and hasn't went since

Comment: Plenty of smoke come from exhaust as its trying to start, there was a dpf delete done a number of years ago would this have an effect on the new brain?

Comment: Car needs gasket around *which* manifold?

Comment: Inlet has been put on still noo joy